# Flag colouring problem (n horizontal stripes)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I have the following problem:
“A flag is to be made with n horizontal stripes by using the colours yellow, blue, green and red in such a way that none of the adjacent stripes have same colour, and neither do the first and last stripe. 
Find the amount of flags that can be made by following the restrictions.”

I solved a similar problem in which the only restriction that I had was that none of the adjacent stripes have the same colour. In order to do it I consider the case in which the nth stripe was red as so the number of flags ($a_n$) were $3a_{n-2}$ 
Since the other cases are basically the same, I got that: $a_n=12a_{n-2}$ 
And so by solving the recurrence I got the answer. 
However, I don’t know how to apply the second restriction that is given in the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the first/last restriction, the recurrence should be $a_n=3a_{n-1}$ because given any flag with $n-1$ stripes you have $3$ choices to make the $n^{th}$ stripe.  The four choices for the first stripe give $a_1=4$ and the general solution is $a_n=4\cdot 3^{n-1}$

Let $b_n$ be the number of flags with $n$ stripes, no neighboring stripes the same, and the same first and last colors.  Let $c_n$ be the number of flags with $n$ stripes, no neighboring stripes the same, and the first and last stripes different.  We can write coupled recurrences
$$a_n=b_n+c_n\\b_n=c_{n-1}\\c_n=3b_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}$$
because a c flag can be extended to a b flag in one way, while a b flag can be extended to a c flag in three ways and a c flag can be extended to a c flag in two ways.  This makes the recurrence $$c_n=2c_{n-1}+3c_{n-2}\\c_n=p3^n+q(-1)^n$$
For initial conditions we have $c_2=12, c_3=4\cdot 3^2-12=24$ giving $p=1,q=3$ and 
$$c_n=3^n+3(-1)^n$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:yes, I dropped a sign.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you get to $c_n = 2c_{n-1} + 3b_{n-1}$? It’s the only part that I’m having troubles to understand

Comment: If you have a flag with $n-1$ stripes that has the top and bottom colors the same (a b flag) you can put any of three colors on the bottom to make a flag with $n$ stripes and the top and bottom different.  If you have a flag with $n-1$ stripes that has the top and bottom colors different (a c flag) you can put two colors on the bottom to make a flag with $n$ stripes and the top and bottom different, because you can't match either the top or bottom.

Comment: Ahhhh sure sure. Now I get it. Thanksss!!

Comment: Ohh, and one last question. Why on the initial conditions you check with $c_2$ and $c_3$? More specifically, why it can’t be checked with $c_1=4$? I tried with that but I get to other values of $p$ and $q$

Comment: I was worried that there might be something special with $c_1$ because there is only one stripe and the concept of different top and bottom stripes is difficult.  My formula has $c_1=0$, presumably because the top and bottom stripes are the same color-they are the same stripe.  I was sure $c_2$ and $c_3$ would fit the pattern.